# Video is not taking full width while playing video

Tags: android, android-videoview, aspect-ratio, textureview

I am playing video in custom textureview. but width couldn't fit properly.

My Custom Texture View

```
public class TextureVideoView extends TextureView
    implements MediaPlayerControl {
    private String TAG = "TextureVideoView";
    // settable by the client
    private Uri mUri;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;

    // all possible internal states
    private static final int STATE_ERROR              = -1;
    private static final int STATE_IDLE               = 0;
    public static final int STATE_PREPARING          = 1;
    private static final int STATE_PREPARED           = 2;
    private static final int STATE_PLAYING            = 3;
    private static final int STATE_PAUSED             = 4;
    private static final int STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED = 5;

    // mCurrentState is a TextureVideoView object's current state.
    // mTargetState is the state that a method caller intends to reach.
    // For instance, regardless the TextureVideoView object's current state,
    // calling pause() intends to bring the object to a target state
    // of STATE_PAUSED.
    private int mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
    private int mTargetState  = STATE_IDLE;

    // All the stuff we need for playing and showing a video
    private Surface     mSurface = null;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
    private int         mAudioSession;
    private int         mVideoWidth;
    private int         mVideoHeight;
    private int         mSurfaceWidth;
    private int         mSurfaceHeight;
    private MediaController mMediaController;
    private OnCompletionListener mOnCompletionListener;
    private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener;
    private int         mCurrentBufferPercentage;
    private OnErrorListener mOnErrorListener;
    private OnInfoListener  mOnInfoListener;
    private int         mSeekWhenPrepared;  // recording the seek position while preparing
    private boolean     mCanPause;
    private boolean     mCanSeekBack;
    private boolean     mCanSeekForward;
    private Context mContext;

    private ScaleType mScaleType;

    private boolean isMute;


    public enum ScaleType {
        CENTER_CROP, TOP, BOTTOM
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initVideoView();
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        initVideoView();
    }

    public TextureVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initVideoView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //Log.i("@@@@", "onMeasure(" + MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec) + ", "
        //        + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec) + ")");

        int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {

            int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int widthSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int heightSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // the size is fixed
                width = widthSpecSize;
                height = heightSpecSize;

                // for compatibility, we adjust size based on aspect ratio
                if ( mVideoWidth * height  < width * mVideoHeight ) {
                    //Log.i("@@@", "image too wide, correcting");
                    width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
                } else if ( mVideoWidth * height  > width * mVideoHeight ) {
                    //Log.i("@@@", "image too tall, correcting");
                    height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
                }
            } else if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // only the width is fixed, adjust the height to match aspect ratio if possible
                width = widthSpecSize;
                height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
                if (heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST && height > heightSpecSize) {
                    // couldn't match aspect ratio within the constraints
                    height = heightSpecSize;
                }
            } else if (heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                // only the height is fixed, adjust the width to match aspect ratio if possible
                height = heightSpecSize;
                width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
                if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST && width > widthSpecSize) {
                    // couldn't match aspect ratio within the constraints
                    width = widthSpecSize;
                }
            } else {
                // neither the width nor the height are fixed, try to use actual video size
                width = mVideoWidth;
                height = mVideoHeight;
                if (heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST && height > heightSpecSize) {
                    // too tall, decrease both width and height
                    height = heightSpecSize;
                    width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
                }
                if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST && width > widthSpecSize) {
                    // too wide, decrease both width and height
                    width = widthSpecSize;
                    height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // no size yet, just adopt the given spec sizes
        }
        LogUtil.w("LOG_TAG", "Mesured Width -->" + width + "Mesured  Height is -->" + height);
       setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
      // super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        event.setClassName(TextureVideoView.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
        info.setClassName(TextureVideoView.class.getName());
    }

    private void initVideoView() {
        mScaleType=ScaleType.BOTTOM;
        mContext = getContext();
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        requestFocus();
        mPendingSubtitleTracks = new Vector<Pair<InputStream, MediaFormat>>();
        mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
        mTargetState  = STATE_IDLE;
    }

    public void setVideoPath(String path) {
        setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    }

    public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
        setVideoURI(uri, null);
    }


    public int getMediaState(){

        return mCurrentState;
    }

    /**
     * @hide
     */
    public void setVideoURI(Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers) {
        LogUtil.e("LOG_TAG","TextureVideoView-->"+ uri);
        mUri = uri;
        mHeaders = headers;
        mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
        openVideo();
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    private Vector<Pair<InputStream, MediaFormat>> mPendingSubtitleTracks;

    public void stopPlayback() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mUri=null;
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
            mTargetState  = STATE_IDLE;
        }
    }

    private void openVideo() {
        if (mUri == null || mSurface == null) {
            // not ready for playback just yet, will try again later
            return;
        }
        // Tell the music playback service to pause
        // TODO: these constants need to be published somewhere in the framework.
        Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        i.putExtra("command", "pause");
        mContext.sendBroadcast(i);

        // we shouldn't clear the target state, because somebody might have
        // called start() previously
        release(false);
        try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            if (mAudioSession != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(mAudioSession);
            } else {
                mAudioSession = mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mPreparedListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mSizeChangedListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mErrorListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(mInfoListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mBufferingUpdateListener);
            mCurrentBufferPercentage = 0;
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, mUri, mHeaders);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(mSurface);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            // we don't set the target state here either, but preserve the
            // target state that was there before.
            mCurrentState = STATE_PREPARING;
            attachMediaController();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to open content: " + mUri, ex);
            mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
            mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
            mErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN, 0);
            return;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to open content: " + mUri, ex);
            mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
            mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
            mErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN, 0);
            return;
        } finally {
            mPendingSubtitleTracks.clear();
        }
    }

    private void attachMediaController() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaController != null) {
            mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
            View anchorView = this.getParent() instanceof View ?
                (View)this.getParent() : this;
            mMediaController.setAnchorView(anchorView);
            mMediaController.setEnabled(isInPlaybackState());
        }
    }

    MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener mSizeChangedListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
            public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
                mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
                if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {
                    getSurfaceTexture().setDefaultBufferSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
                    requestLayout();
                }
            }
        };

    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mCurrentState = STATE_PREPARED;

            mCanPause = mCanSeekBack = mCanSeekForward = true;

            if (mOnPreparedListener != null) {
                mOnPreparedListener.onPrepared(mMediaPlayer);
            }
            if (mMediaController != null) {
                mMediaController.setEnabled(true);
            }
            mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
            mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

            LogUtil.w("LOG_TAG","Video Width is -->"+ mVideoWidth + "Video Height is -->"+ mVideoHeight);

            int seekToPosition = mSeekWhenPrepared;  // mSeekWhenPrepared may be changed after seekTo() call
            if (seekToPosition != 0) {
                seekTo(seekToPosition);
            }
            if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {
                //Log.i("@@@@", "video size: " + mVideoWidth +"/"+ mVideoHeight);
                getSurfaceTexture().setDefaultBufferSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
                if (mSurfaceWidth == mVideoWidth && mSurfaceHeight == mVideoHeight) {
                    // We didn't actually change the size (it was already at the size
                    // we need), so we won't get a "surface changed" callback, so
                    // start the video here instead of in the callback.
                    if (mTargetState == STATE_PLAYING) {
                        start();
                        if (mMediaController != null) {
                            mMediaController.show();
                        }
                    } else if (!isPlaying() &&
                        (seekToPosition != 0 || getCurrentPosition() > 0)) {
                        if (mMediaController != null) {
                            // Show the media controls when we're paused into a video and make 'em stick.
                            mMediaController.show(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // We don't know the video size yet, but should start anyway.
                // The video size might be reported to us later.
                if (mTargetState == STATE_PLAYING) {
                    start();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener =
        new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (mCurrentState == STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED) {
                // sprylab bugfix: on some devices onCompletion is called twice
                return;
            }
                mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED;
                mTargetState = STATE_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED;
                if (mMediaController != null) {
                    mMediaController.hide();
                }
                if (mOnCompletionListener != null) {
                    mOnCompletionListener.onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
                }
            }
        };

    private OnInfoListener mInfoListener =
        new OnInfoListener() {
            public  boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1, int arg2) {
                if (mOnInfoListener != null) {
                    mOnInfoListener.onInfo(mp, arg1, arg2);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

    private OnErrorListener mErrorListener =
        new OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int framework_err, int impl_err) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + framework_err + "," + impl_err);
                mCurrentState = STATE_ERROR;
                mTargetState = STATE_ERROR;
                if (mMediaController != null) {
                    mMediaController.hide();
                }

            /* If an error handler has been supplied, use it and finish. */
                if (mOnErrorListener != null) {
                    if (mOnErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, framework_err, impl_err)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

            /* Otherwise, pop up an error dialog so the user knows that
             * something bad has happened. Only try and pop up the dialog
             * if we're attached to a window. When we're going away and no
             * longer have a window, don't bother showing the user an error.
             */
                if (getWindowToken() != null) {
                    Resources r = mContext.getResources();
                    int messageId;

                    if (framework_err == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK) {
                        messageId = R.string.VideoView_error_text_invalid_progressive_playback;
                    } else {
                        messageId = R.string.VideoView_error_text_unknown;
                    }

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                        .setMessage(messageId)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.VideoView_error_button,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        /* If we get here, there is no onError listener, so
                                         * at least inform them that the video is over.
                                         */
                                    if (mOnCompletionListener != null) {
                                        mOnCompletionListener.onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

    private MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener mBufferingUpdateListener =
        new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                mCurrentBufferPercentage = percent;
            }
        };

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when the media file
     * is loaded and ready to go.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will be run
     */
    public void setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener l)
    {
        mOnPreparedListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when the end of a media file
     * has been reached during playback.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will be run
     */
    public void setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener l)
    {
        mOnCompletionListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when an error occurs
     * during playback or setup.  If no listener is specified,
     * or if the listener returned false, TextureVideoView will inform
     * the user of any errors.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will be run
     */
    public void setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener l)
    {
        mOnErrorListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when an informational event
     * occurs during playback or setup.
     *
     * @param l The callback that will be run
     */
    public void setOnInfoListener(OnInfoListener l) {
        mOnInfoListener = l;
    }

    SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new SurfaceTextureListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {
            mSurfaceWidth = width;
            mSurfaceHeight = height;
            boolean isValidState =  (mTargetState == STATE_PLAYING);
            boolean hasValidSize = (mVideoWidth == width && mVideoHeight == height);
            if (mMediaPlayer != null && isValidState && hasValidSize) {
                if (mSeekWhenPrepared != 0) {
                    seekTo(mSeekWhenPrepared);
                }
                start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surface, final int width, final int height) {
            mSurface = new Surface(surface);
            openVideo();


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(final SurfaceTexture surface) {
            // after we return from this we can't use the surface any more
            if (mSurface != null) {
                mSurface.release();
                mSurface = null;
            }
            if (mMediaController != null) mMediaController.hide();
            release(true);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(final SurfaceTexture surface) {
            // do nothing
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();

        if(mUri!=null){
            LogUtil.e("LOG_TAG","TextureVideo View is hidden-->"+ mUri.getPath());
            stopPlayback();
        }

    }

    /*
         * release the media player in any state
         */
    private void release(boolean cleartargetstate) {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            mPendingSubtitleTracks.clear();
            mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
            if (cleartargetstate) {
                mTargetState  = STATE_IDLE;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isInPlaybackState() && mMediaController != null) {
            toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isInPlaybackState() && mMediaController != null) {
            toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        boolean isKeyCodeSupported = keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL &&
            keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL;
        if (isInPlaybackState() && isKeyCodeSupported && mMediaController != null) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK ||
                keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    pause();
                    mMediaController.show();
                } else {
                    start();
                    mMediaController.hide();
                }
                return true;
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY) {
                if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    start();
                    mMediaController.hide();
                }
                return true;
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE) {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    pause();
                    mMediaController.show();
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void toggleMediaControlsVisiblity() {
        if (mMediaController.isShowing()) {
            mMediaController.hide();
        } else {
            mMediaController.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYING;
        }
        mTargetState = STATE_PLAYING;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
                Constants.VIDEO_LENGTH = 0;
                Constants.VIDEO_LENGTH = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mCurrentState = STATE_PAUSED;
            }
        }
        mTargetState = STATE_PAUSED;
    }

    public void suspend() {
        release(false);
    }

    public void resume() {
        openVideo();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int msec) {
        if (isInPlaybackState()) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(msec);
            mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
        } else {
            mSeekWhenPrepared = msec;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return isInPlaybackState() && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            return mCurrentBufferPercentage;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private boolean isInPlaybackState() {
        return (mMediaPlayer != null &&
            mCurrentState != STATE_ERROR &&
            mCurrentState != STATE_IDLE &&
            mCurrentState != STATE_PREPARING);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return mCanPause;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return mCanSeekBack;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return mCanSeekForward;
    }

    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        if (mAudioSession == 0) {
            MediaPlayer foo = new MediaPlayer();
            mAudioSession = foo.getAudioSessionId();
            foo.release();
        }
        return mAudioSession;
    }
}
```

after using this texture view i am getting video like this  [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i79Cw.jpg)

and i need like this [Video image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeUlw.jpg)

please suggest what should i do to fill full width

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
    mScaleType=ScaleType.BOTTOM;
```

to

```
 mScaleType=ScaleType.FIT_XY;
```

If you have still same issue then check your layouts that is set to match_parent or not.and set your scaleType.FIT_XY in the fnction where video start playing.